# iOS 8: Camera: manual EV slider

Tags: ios, camera, avfoundation, avcapturedevice

**Prerequisites:** iOS 8, native app
**The task:** develop slider that is shown above camera view. Slider must change camera's **EV** from its' lowest value to the highest value possible.

**The questions:**

1. How to calculate maximum possible/minimum possible/current EV value via ISO and shutter speed I have in iOS SDK? (Have I?) This is required to understand the step of the slider relative to its' movement.
2. How should I setup EV value properly on slider movement? As I understand I can change both ISO and shutter speed. How should I use them to change EV from its' min to max as the slider moves?

Comment: Have you got any solution..? I have to do this things into my App.

Comment: Have you find any solution...?

Comment: @MeetDoshi All that we could do is using the native EV management interface.

Comment: Please share demo code. I have to do this same thing into my app. But I didn't get any solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came here to close this question with the answer.

These tutorials and open-source sample code gives a complete understanding of how to implement what originally was queried about:

1. Nice Xamarin tutorial about Camera Manual Controls. Completely applies to **native**. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/intro_to_manual_camera_controls/
2. Watch this official Apple Video about Custom Camera Controls: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/508/
3. Get their presentation: http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/508xxfvaehrll14/508/508_camera_capture_manual_controls.pdf
4. And try their awesome samples:
   4.1. AvCamManual https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCamManual/Introduction/Intro.html
   4.2. and BracketStripes https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BracketStripes/Introduction/Intro.html

Now you are fully loaded.

Here is the result of what we delivered: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/slidecam/id1046798471?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code, and you can able to set EV value of your custom camera. Make sure that, slider's value is between -8 to 8.

```
- (IBAction)changeValueOfEVSliderAction:(id)sender
{
    UISlider *control = sender;
    NSError *error = nil;
    AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    if ( [videoDevice lockForConfiguration:&error] ) {
        [videoDevice setExposureTargetBias:control.value completionHandler:nil];
        [videoDevice unlockForConfiguration];
        //self.exposureTargetBiasValueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", control.value];
    }
}
```

As answer of @DaddyM, Please refer this [AVCamManual: Extending AVCam to Use Manual Capture API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCamManual/Introduction/Intro.html) for more details.